# JTextArea issue

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, word-wrap

I'm having an issue with resizing of JTextArea in java.swing. The problem is that once the current line is finished (so for example if i keep pressing space) - it doesn't go to the second line - it just keeps on going. Same thing when i press enter - it stretches out the box vertically. How do I prevent this? I'm using GridBagLayout.

```
JTextArea MainText = new JTextArea();
MainText.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16));
MainText.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
c.insets = new Insets (10, 10, 10, 10);
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 2;
c.weightx = 1.0;
c.weighty = 1.0;
c.gridwidth = 3;
c.gridheight = 1;
panel.add(MainText, c);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the [`lineWrap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setLineWrap%28boolean%29) and [`wrapStyleWord`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setWrapStyleWord%28boolean%29) properties of the `JTextArea`

```
JTextArea MainText = new JTextArea();
MainText.setLineWrap(true);
MainText.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

Take a look at [How to use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) for more details

You might also find having a read through [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) of some use

Unless you really don't want to, I would also suggest adding the `JTextArea` into a `JScrollPane` instead of adding it directly to the conatiner

```
panel.add(new JScrollPane(MainText), c);
```

This will prevent the `JTextArea` from wanting to grow as more text is added to it (unless that's what you're going for)

Comment: That's excellent, i've managed to find how to do the linewraps myself but the area was still resizing vertically until i put the jscrollpane in place. Is there a way to change the borders back? they do look different now

Comment: You need to change the border of the `JScrollPane` to what ever you want

Comment: by using new JScrollPane(MainText) i'm not really giving the object a name so what do i refer to when i use the BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder()?

Comment: So don't.  Assign the instance of `JScrollPane` to a local variable...`JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(MainText);` then add the reference to the container, after you've made your modifications.

Answer (score 3):

To get your JTextAreas to wrap lines on words appropriately, use: `mainText.setWrapStyleWord(true)` and `mainText.setLineWrap(true)`

Most important though, get very familiar with using the Java API as it will likely answer 90% of similar questions:

[JTextArea API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: and +1 back at you.